# open php file in browser (address bar) with php attributes set

Tags: php

This might be a basic question, but I cant get a hit on the web for it:

I have a PHP file ready to take input from an html post,

For example:

```
$var = $_POST["web-page-var"];
```

Is it possible to open the php file in a browser with the variable statically set already e.g. something like this in the browser`s address bar:

http://my.site/myPHPfile.php_&_web-page-var=some-value

Also, is it possible to include more than one variable?

Comment: Yes, you would need to use a GET method though.

Comment: Adding to Fred's suggestion, you would also need to fix that url format. The first name value pair needs to have `?` before it and then `&` between the remaining ones.

Comment: You almost have it right: you need a "?" between the URL and the params, and you must use GET to "get" the params from the URL

Comment: for sending by URL, you need `GET` method. Unless you're going to send lots of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is what **[GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)** request method is for, not `POST`

You can do `http://yoursite.com/test.php?a=1&b=2`

And access those in PHP like

```
$a=$_GET["a"];
$b=$_GET["b"];
```

Once you get that going, you can add some conditional checks to grab the values only if they are present. For example

```
if(isset($_GET["a"]))
  $a=$_GET["a"];
```

Comment: @bingo12345 You probably want to check for POST first, then for GET and use an empty value if nothing is found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes yous can use this http://test.com/file.php?a=1&b=2&c=3

for access to calue of variables

$var1=$GET['a'];
,.....

For Use Post You Just Need Advanced Tool With Browser Like Firebug to set post variabe in web file

Answer (score 0):

This can be done commonly for both post and get using $_REQUEST variable. The code can be follows.

$var = $_REQUEST[web-page-var]

See following url: http://sugunan.net/demo/request.php?web-page-var=your-value&name=your-name&mail=your-mail

Here you can change the value and test it will show the exact value you pass on the url.

The exact code of that url is follows.

```
<pre>
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

if you want any customization let me know i can apply it and send.